# C++ template class having constructor with template

Tags: c++, templates

So I have some basic class **A** like this:

```
template<class T1>
class A {
public:
    X* x;

    template <class T2>
    A(const A<T2> &a) {
        x = new X(a->x);
    }
};
```

Where both T1 and T2 will be of types inheriting from X. However, this code does not work and I truly cannot understand how I would write it in order for the constructor to be able to take another **A** with a potentially different template argument.

So to make it clear I want to write a constructor that takes will be able to take an **A** with a different template parameter. (The code compiles as it is, the template part just doesn't seem to work the way I want it to).

What I want to be able to do: (Where both **Y** and **Z** inherit from **X**)

```
A<Z> a1;
A<Y> a2(a1);
```

Any help is very appreciated!

**Sorry I thought I would be able to create a good example** and not have to use my actual code, but it seems I have failed a bit with the syntax, so here is my real class cut down a bit:

```
template <class T>
class Calendar {
private:
    Date *d;
public:
    template <class T2>
    Calendar(const Calendar<T2> &c) {
        d = new T(c.view_date_component());
    }
    Calendar();
    ~Calendar();
    const Date& view_date_component() const;
};

template <class T>
Calendar<T>::Calendar() {
    d = new T();
}

template <class T>
Calendar<T>::~Calendar() {
    delete d;
}

template <class T>
const Date& Calendar<T>::view_date_component() const {
    return *d;
}
```

Comment: how do you use the `A` constructor? can you create a small `main()` describing the case and show what result you expect?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with templates. You're misusing pointers and references (e.g. using `->` on a reference).

Comment: You need a default constructor as well to do this.

Comment: I may have done something wrong with the pointers in my example, but I assure you that the real problem my code has is with the templates

Comment: Is there a compilation error?

Comment: It compiles, and my code has a default constructor and support for all the X-related operations exist, it just crashes when I run. If I let T2 be T1 it works, just not when their template argument is different.

Comment: What you posted would not compile, due in part to what I wrote before. Please post a minimal compilable example.

Comment: What you posted now is neither minimal nor compilable. Since your code compiles, it's impossible to say what causes the crash without seeing relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you'll need to define a default constructor as well. Secondly, you would have to make the template class a friend of itself to access private member variable x. Thirdly, in your template constructor you're passing `a` as `const` reference. Consequently, you can't access a member of it with `->` (i.e., arrow operator) but rather with `.` (i.e., dot operator).

```
template<class T1>
class A {
  X* x;
 public:
   A() = default;
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   template <class T2>
   A(const A<T2> &a) {
     x = new X(*(a.x));
               ^^^^^^
   }

  template<class T2> friend class A;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ff56fa73d711051)

If you want the template constructor to be evoked only if `T1` and `T2` inherit from `X`:

```
template <typename T2, 
typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X, T1>::value && 
                                   std::is_base_of<X, T2>::value>::type>
A(const A<T2> &a) {
    x = new X(*(a.x));
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/619efa2b03d2a926)

Comment: Down-voters please be so kind to explain the reason of your down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check of T2 extends X or exends T1, you can use SFINAE with [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
template <class T2, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<X, T2>>>
A(const A<T2> &a) {
    x = new X(a->x);
}
```